# How to get Random of two specific numbers?

Tags: mysql

E.g.

The first number is: 429
The second number is: 529

**So I want to write MySQL query in such a way that, it should give me either 429 or 529 exactly.**

I searched on google regarding this, but its showing results for a random number as a range.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

My real requirement is this:

```
INSERT INTO table1(table2_id, status, stage, added_by)
(SELECT id, 'Pending', 'Semifinal', RAND(SELECT 429 UNION SELECT 529) FROM table2)
```

Comment: "So I want to write mysql query in such a way that, it should give me either 429 or 529 exactly." isn't this line clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 429 UNION SELECT 529) AS tmp ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Steps:

1. Select 429 and 529
2. Apply random order
3. Return first result

Comment: this answer will also generate the column header random named 429 or 529.. You might want the change this anwser into `SELECT number FROM (SELECT 429 AS number UNION SELECT 529 AS number) AS tmp ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` to give you a stable column header named number.

Answer (score 1):

The function is the following (without `UNION` and `ORDER`, only math and only one step):

`(ROUND(RAND()) * 100) + 429`

or

`(FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 2)) * 100) + 429`

Refer to MySQL [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

**APPENDED**

To give a general answer to the question (to select one random integer from any two integers `:x` and `:y`):

`(FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 2)) * (:y - :x)) + :x`

This way does not create a mem table and does not sort the rows in it and/or fetch one of the random rows.

Comment: @rahulsm I gave an exact answer to your question. You told us not a single word that there could be other numbers. Have you read the posted link? There is the MySQL answer to the question how to randomly pick an integer number. You can select `0` or `1` and multyply by `(y - x)` and add `x` to the result. In the case you will get `x` (if random is 0) or `x + 1 *(y - x) = y` if random is `1`.

Comment: @rahulsm Please try the appended code from my answer before arguing. It does not give a number from the range `(x; y)`. It gets the numbers `x` _or_ `y`. It will work for the proposed 10234 and 12391 and other numbers.

Comment: This works, sorry mate! I was checking for your above code... not the appended code... I got this working [here](http://rextester.com/PYAE85836)

Comment: @rahulsm The first two code snippets do not give values from within the range also, They give exacly the upper and lower borders from your Q (429 and 529).

Comment: but I want to give two input numbers(any numbers), your first case works for 429 & 529 and take only one number as input.

Comment: @rahulsm OK I hope the code helps you to do what you want without `ORDER BY` and `UNION` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is this data placed within a table? Then something like this might work:

`SELECT number FROM table ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1`

Comment: I updated my requirement. I don't want query to get random results, I want random numbers from two numbers i.e. either 429 or 529, and query results will be sequential only.